# How to display photo from non-public folder?

Tags: php

I have built my website in a way so that the actual database files are positioned as follows

```
root/
root/httpdocs <- public folder
root/databasefolder/actual_files_here/some_photo.jpg
```

How can I implement so that the php can view/load a photo from that databasefolder and echo it with  tag. I simply tried `"../databasefolder/"` in a  tag, but it doesn't work (of course it doesn't), since it's from hidden folder.

I tried Base64 which works in other browsers, but not with Internet Explorer, due to that silly kb limit.

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML:

```
<img src="image.php?image=some_photo.jpg" />
```

And a php script that echoes your image.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo imagejpeg('root/databasefolder/actual_files_here/' . $_GET['image']);
```

You can use the get parameter "image" to load whatever image you need from that folder.

Comment: I didn't get it to work with your answer exactly, however I did found it extremely helpful. I greated a second .php file which I use to generate images fetched from the folder (since php has an access to those folders).

Then I simply use the image data echoed by that .php file as the <img src=""> data as you mentioned. I simply replaced imagejpeg() function with readfile(). For some reason imagejpeg kepts giving me "...contains errors... " error.